# Mod question: $-5 \pmod 3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How come $-5 \equiv 1  \pmod 3$ and not $-5 \equiv 2\ $ or $\ -2  \pmod{3}$?

$-\frac{5}{3}= -1 -\frac{2}{3}$. 
i.e. Remainder is $-2$ or $2$?

Comment: What do you mean by $\frac{-5}{3} ~(mod 3)$? You have $3\equiv 0~ (mod 3)$, thus you are dividing by $0$.

Comment: Actually, it *is* true that $-5\equiv-2\pmod{3}$, but it is also true (and more natural to think about, in my opinion) that $-2\equiv1\pmod{3}$, thus $-5\equiv1\pmod{3}$. One way to think about the congruence classes is to add (or subtract) any multiples of $3$.

Comment: What 3 numbers would you want to use to work mod 3? {0,1,2} and {-1,0,1} would be the most common ones I'd think.

Comment: $$-5 \equiv 1  \pmod 3$$ because $3|(-5 - 1)$

Comment: Thank you everyone. Modular arithmetic is not in my curriculum and all of your comments/answers have been extremely helpful! Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$-5 \equiv 1 [3]$ because you have

$$-5 = 1 + (-2)\times 3$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $-5 \pmod{3} \equiv -5 + 3\cdot 2 \pmod{3} \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$.

Alternatively, simply note that $$-5 = 1 + 3 \cdot -2 \implies -5 = 1\pmod{3}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The other answers already give you enough ways to get to $5\equiv -1\equiv 2 ~(\operatorname{mod}3) $, I just want to say something about your notation.

You can't just look at fractions the way you're used to in $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb R$. Strictly speaking:
we have an equivalence relation on $\mathbb Z\times \left(\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}\right)$ defined as $$(m,n)\sim (j,k):\Leftrightarrow mk=nj.$$ One then defines $$\mathbb Q:=\{[(m,n)]~|~(m,n)\in \mathbb Z\times \left(\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}\right)\}$$ where $[(m,n)]$ is the equivalence class of this equivalence relation.

Now, for $p,q\in\mathbb Z,q\neq 0$ one usually writes $\frac{p}{q}$ instead of $[(p,q)]$ and also interpretes it as $p/q$ or $p:q$ (both meaning "$p$ divided by $q$"). So a fraction is just another notation for the equivalence class $[(p,q)]$. If one now defines addition/multiplication to make $\mathbb Q$ the wellknown field, another notation can be $[(p,q)]=p\cdot q^{-1}$ (which also coincides with notation for groups etc.).

If you now have $\frac{5}{3}~(\operatorname{mod} 3)$ you'd first have to clarify what you mean by that, as $5\cdot 3^{-1}$ is not well-defined in $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would think of it is like this: if $n \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, then $n = 3m + 1$, and if $n \equiv 2 \pmod 3$, then $n = 3m + 2$, for some integer $m$. With $-5$, we have $m = -2$ and then $-5 = 3m + 1$, therefore $-5 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

When you learn about ideals, you can say that the multiples of $3$ are $\langle 3 \rangle$. Then $-5$ belongs in $\langle 3 \rangle + 1$ and $5$ belongs in $\langle 3 \rangle + 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Add multiples of $3$. If we add $6$ we see that $-5 + 0 \pmod 3 \equiv (-5 + 6) \pmod 3 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.